# Simplify an expression under certain condition

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have a variable A = g / (1 + g R)
Actually, if the quantity (g R) >> 1 it is possible to write A as A ≈ 1/R.
How can I do this in Mathematica?
I tried with Assumptions, Refine, Simplify, but i can get the simplified form.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `Series`.

Comment: Or a `Limit`. You have to prepare your expression so that the thing you want to make go to infinity/zero/whatever is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange the equation a bit, it is straightforward. Define a new variable x = g R. Then g = x/R and A = g/(1+g R) = (x/R)/(1+x). What you wish to calculate is the limit (as suggested by Rojo)

```
Limit[(x/R)/(1 + x), x -> Infinity]
1/R
```

Answer (score 1):

As b.gatessucks suggested in his comment above, this is a good spot for `Series`.  You can get the Taylor series expansion of your expression about infinity as

```
Series[g/(1 + g R), {R, Infinity, 2}]
```

which yields the result

```
1/R-1/(g R^2)+O[1/R]^3
```

Now you only need adjust the number of terms in the series expansion to suit your purposes...